# Get Root Structure Group metadata in DXA 2.0 Pages

Tags: web8.5, metadata

We are using the R2 Data Model builder InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder, in order to add the metadata of an SG on the page. However, there's no a recursive behavior there.

SG 1 (Metadata) > SG 2 > Page

When publishing the page, we don't get the metadata of the SG1. In the previous Tridion version, this was possible. Does it exist a way of doing that nowadays with TBB?

If we try SG 1 (Metadata)  > Page, this works. But we expected to have the same functionality as in previous versions. If the parent folder doesn't have metadata, recursively ask to the grandparent folder for metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the [InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/blob/master/Sdl.Web.Tridion.Templates.R2/Data/InheritMetadataPageModelBuilder.cs) does go “up the tree” to collect SG metadata, but it may be in a different way than you expect: it collects SG metadata for ancestor SGs until it finds a SG without a metadata Schema.